# Accessing libgui.so api on a rooted device

Tags: android, android-ndk

For a proof-of-concept for a school project, I need to access the system library from my native code in Android ndk. I have already successfully linked to libgui.so, libui.so... etc.

However, some of the functions cannot be accessed. Specifically, I used the ISurfaceComposer to capture the screen onto a BufferQueue. I tried using BufferQueue->acquireBuffer to read the frame but adb gives me an error "disconnected : unknown API".

I've tried moving the app and its library into the system folder but still the same result. Is there any way to access these system libraries without building the whole Android system?

Edit: Native code

```
const String16 name("SurfaceFlinger");
sp<ISurfaceComposer> composer;
getService(name, &composer);


sp <BufferQueue> bufferQueue = new BufferQueue();
wp <BufferQueue::ConsumerListener> listener = 
    static_cast<BufferQueue::ConsumerListener*>(this);
sp <BufferQueue::ProxyConsumerListener> proxy = 
    new BufferQueue::ProxyConsumerListener(listener);

status_t err = bufferQueue->consumerConnect(proxy, false);
if (err == NO_INIT)
    return "NO INIT";
else if (err == BAD_VALUE)
    return "BAD_VALUE";
else if (err != NO_ERROR)
    return "CONNECTION FAILED";

uint32_t w = 0;
uint32_t h = 0;

status_t err = composer->captureScreen(0, bufferQueue, w, h, 0, 0);
if (err != NO_ERROR)
    return "NOPE";

BufferQueue::BufferItem item;
err = bufferQueue->acquireBuffer(&item, 0);
if (err == BufferQueue::NO_BUFFER_AVAILABLE)
    return "NAH";
else if (err == NO_ERROR)
    return "NAH2";
else if (err == INVALID_OPERATION)
    return "NAH3";
else if (err == BufferQueue::PRESENT_LATER)
    return "NAH4";



return "HOPE";
```

Edit 2: Error from Log Files

```
02-08 09:56:18.318 5612-5612/com.mikaaudio.server E/BufferQueue: [unnamed-5612-0] disconnect: unknown API 0
```

Comment: You should link against the libraries that are in your target device system/lib. Also, it will be easier to help you if you post the relevant piece of code.

Comment: I added the code in my cpp file. The function returns with "NAH2". I actually followed your solution in another question to link against libraries in system/lib using the variable LOCAL_LDLIBS, so.

Comment: According to the source, [`acquireBuffer()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/kitkat-release/libs/gui/BufferQueue.cpp#863) could return **NO_ERROR**, **INVALID_OPERATION**, **NO_BUFFER_AVAILABLE**, or **PRESENT_LATER**.

Comment: I have edited my code to check for these four values. However, the function now returns "HOPE". I have also included the one line of error in the log file. The app works normally otherwise. It does not crash.

Comment: I believe that you get there because [binderDied()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/kitkat-release/libs/gui/BufferQueue.cpp#707) is toggled, with **mConnectedApi** == **NO_CONNECTED_API**. You probably must call [BufferQueue::connect()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/kitkat-release/libs/gui/BufferQueue.cpp#640) before acquiring a buffer.

Comment: I've added code to connect to the bufferqueue before acquiring the buffer. BufferQueue::consumerConnect() can return NO_INIT, BAD_VALUE or NO_ERROR. But it returns none of them. I've also tried changing consumerConnect to consumerConnect(NULL, false) to force a BAD_VALUE return. However, it still returned an unknown status_t. I tried matching it to ones found in Errors.h, but found no match. I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102910/discussion-between-alex-cohn-and-aaycee).

Comment: Re: **typeinfo Android::RefBase** this could be result of your compiler settings. Did you spcify `-fno-rtti`?